# image dimensions oddity

Tags: javascript, css, image, height, dimensions

```
el = function(q) {return document.getElementById(q)};
el('strange').style.height = '100px'
el('strange').height = 2000
alert(el('strange').height) // 100?
alert(el('strange').getAttribute('height')) //2000? Wait.. What?
```

el is a shorthand of document.getElementById. Can someone explain me what's going on? I suspect that the height property is slightly different than the height attribute: they modified it so it returns the computed style. I'm not sure, because DOM 0 says that the property should be the same as the getAttribute, but the href property of an anchor doesn't match with the getAttribute in most browsers. And:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement

The HTML:

```
<img id="strange" src="http://images.devshed.com/fcw/belts/fcw_forums.gif" />
```

Comment: No, I'll add the html for this example...

Answer (score 0):

The oddity isn't exaclty were you're spotting it. It comes from the fact that the call to the height attribute as a setter is creating a **html** height attribute in the img tag, and as far as I know, it's an attribute used only for canvas. There is no connection between this html tag and the dom value.

If i do the following:

```
strange.style.height = '100px';
strange.height = 2000;
console.log(strange.height); // 100
console.log(strange.style.height); // 100px
```

the output will be `100` and  `100px` the height on the **DOM** is correct. However, using the getAttribute  search for the attributes in the html tag, therefor returning "2000".

**EDIT**

Ok i think i got it

There are 3 different stuff:
The css height, the height attribute, the height DOM value.

The easiest is the DOM value. It always return the img real height in css pixel. If set trhough css, it will be based on the css value, if set through attribute, it will be calculated from that.

Now the two other.

They both specify the img dimension. But the css value as precedence over the HTML attribute.
This is stated in the [w3 recommandation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height). I quote

For

> Inline replaced elements, block-level replaced elements in normal flow, 'inline-block' replaced elements in normal flow and floating replaced elements

It's stated that

> If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the element also has an intrinsic height, then that intrinsic height is the used value of 'height'.

Therefore, img (who are inline-block element I think) use the height css value, but if this one is set to auto (and it's the default) it uses the `intrinsic height`. And that is the html attribute.

So calling `strange.height` as a getter gets the DOM value, and as a setter, it sets the HTML attribute.

**EDIT2** And to answer more exactly, you have 3 basic rules:

- CSS prevails over attribute
- DOM should be the same as attribute
- DOM reflects the reality (here the real height)

You just can't follow the 3 rules if both CSS and attribute value are specified and differ.
The point is DOM **should** be the same. Here it can't be if there is CSS, so it has a different value.

As a side note, a nice explanation of the use of the height attribute here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/img .

Comment: No, that's not true, if you don't set the style (if you remove the first line of your script), the image will be 2000px high...

Comment: And what are returning the strange.height and strange.style.height? They both have a 2000 value?

Comment: No, strange.style.height returns '100px' (string), strange.height returns 100 (long), strange.getAttribute('height') returns '2000' (string)

Comment: I meant in the case `strange.style.height = '100px';` was removed.

Comment: Hum when I read you question again, I have a doubt, is your question about the different kind of height (see edited answer), or about the difference between the .height and the getAttribute('height')?

Comment: I thought this too, but then I read the w3c specs and saw there isn't such thing as a DOM value.

Comment: @Py let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3040/discussion-between-bopjesvla-and-py)